# Select row in react-data-table-component how to deactivate multiple select

Tags: react-data-table-component

I'm using react data table component i wanna use a radio button to select a row , i using checkbox how can i deactivate multiple select

```
 <Table
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                    selectableRows={true}
                    conditionalRowStyles={conditionalRowStyles}
                    onRowClicked={handleRowClicked}
                    onSelectedRowsChange={handleRowSelected}
                    clearSelectedRows={true}
                />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **selectableRowsSingle** property.

```
 <Table
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                selectableRows={true}

                selectableRowsSingle

                conditionalRowStyles={conditionalRowStyles}
                onRowClicked={handleRowClicked}
                onSelectedRowsChange={handleRowSelected}
                clearSelectedRows={true}
            />
```